# AWS how to access via SSH an instance from my OSX console as a user

Tags: amazon-web-services, osx-mavericks, ssh-keys

I am correctly accessing an AWS Ubuntu instance via SSH from my OSX console via the standard ubuntu root  (I copied the was public key in my ~/.ssh local directory

```
ssh -i  ~/.ssh/aws-publickey.pem ubuntu@ec2-54-187-218-213.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

However , I'ld like to access via a user account with admin rights..

I try to understand the 'huge' AWS documentation, I created an IAM, aws user account 'joe' , but then I don't know what are the following steps ...

- should I use OpsWork ( as stated) to add a public key to this user ?
- is this public key my id_rsa.pub , I have on my Mac for this user 'joe' in ~/.ssh
- or should I re-use the same public key ~/.ssh/aws-publickey.pem ?

thanks for enlightenment ...

Comment: You can "sudo -s" to become root after logged in as ubuntu... was this the question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confusing IAM users (accounts on Amazon Web Services) and user accounts on a Linux box. These are not related in any way.

The IAM user account `joe` you have created can be assigned fine grained permissions to perform  any functions you can perform at the AWS console such as launch servers, take snapshots etc. It has nothing to do with user accounts on the Linux boxes you launch.

Initially the only user accounts on a fresh Ubuntu box are the `ubuntu` account which you can log in with, and the `root` account which is the super user or admin account you refer to. I suspect you are coming from a Windows background, because it is not common practice to have multiple "admin" accounts.

If a user needs access to elevated permissions they would usually be assigned some level of `sudo` access which offers fine grained control over what they can do. Your `ubuntu` account already has full sudo access so you can run any command as root with `sudo command`.

In order for you to have a `joe` account on the new Linux box you would have to:

- Log in as ubuntu (as this is the only account accessible via ssh initially)
- Create a new user account (you need to be root to do this so either use `sudo` or become root first with `sudo su -`). Run `man adduser` to see the command for adding a user account.
- Copy your `~/ssh/id_rsa.pub` file from your Mac to `~/.ssh` on the new linux account.
- Make sure the `.ssh` directory and contents can't be modified by running `chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh` or ssh will refuse to connect without a password.